# Copying data from sheet to single row, delete then pasting row to last row on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been hitting my head on the desk attempting to wrack my brain in attempt to get the answer, but it seems to me that my brain just doesn't want to work. I've gotten this far, but it seems no further...

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Internal NCMR
    Dim wsInt As Worksheet
    Dim wsNDA As Worksheet

    'Copy Ranges
    Dim c As Variant

    'Paste Ranges
    Dim p As Range

    'Setting Sheet
    Set wsInt = Sheets("Internal NCMR")
    Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")
    Set p = Range("B54:U54")

    With wsInt
        c = Array(.Range("B11"), .Range("B14"), .Range("B17"), .Range("B20"), .Range("B23"), .Range("Q11") _
                , .Range("Q14"), .Range("Q17"), .Range("Q20"), .Range("R25"), .Range("V23"), .Range("V25") _
                , .Range("V27"), .Range("B32"), .Range("B36"), .Range("B40"), .Range("B44"), .Range("D49") _
                , .Range("L49"), .Range("V49"))
    End With

    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        p(i + 1).Value = c(i).Value
    Next

    With wsNDA
        Worksheets("Internal NCMR").Rows("54").Copy
        Sheets("NCMR Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

The point of this script as explained in the topic is three fold.

1. Take fields from a sheet, paste them into a row.
2. Take row delete it,and paste it into another sheet in same workbook.
3. Copy from 2nd sheet from cell Z1 to beginning of row just inserted.

The third part I haven't gotten to yet, if someone could help me with that it be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you run the sub?

Comment: I came back with a validation error on Worksheets for some reason, never figured out why really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValues()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Internal NCMR
    Dim wsInt As Worksheet
    Dim wsNDA As Worksheet

    'Copy Ranges
    Dim c As Variant

    'Paste Ranges
    Dim p As Range

    'Setting Sheet
    Set wsInt = Sheets("Internal NCMR")
    Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")
    Set p = wsInt.Range("B54:U54")

    With wsInt
        c = Array(.Range("B11"), .Range("B14"), .Range("B17"), .Range("B20"), .Range("B23"), .Range("Q11") _
                , .Range("Q14"), .Range("Q17"), .Range("Q20"), .Range("R25"), .Range("V23"), .Range("V25") _
                , .Range("V27"), .Range("B32"), .Range("B36"), .Range("B40"), .Range("B44"), .Range("D49") _
                , .Range("L49"), .Range("V49"))
    End With

    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        p(i + 1).Value = c(i).Value
    Next

    With wsNDA
        Dim Lastrow As Long

        Lastrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        wsInt.Rows("54").Copy

        With .Rows(Lastrow)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End With

        With .Range("A" & Lastrow)
            If Lastrow = 3 Then
                .Value = 1
            Else
                .Value = Val(wsNDA.Range("A" & Lastrow - 1).Value) + 1
            End If

            .NumberFormat = "0#######"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, Yes and no...It A1:Y, and then Z would be pasted into column A where the rest was posted onto.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand. could you please give me an exmaple?

Comment: Sure, here... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Int.xlsm

This has the script, and the example inside it, instead of being Z1 it is V2.

Comment: Sorry got caught up in another question :) I think I know what you want... You want to increment the number by 1?

Comment: If yes, then see the post above I have updated it. This also negates the use of An auto number field in cell Y

Comment: It works, but the numbering on NCMR# doesn't. It keeps on posting 01 no matter how many times I post. Also, the row 54 doesn't delete from the original sheet after it's been pasted over. It seems the script is just copy and pasting not deleting and pasting.

Comment: Thanks it works nearly perfectly, only one question, part of the original code attempted to deleted the original row then paste it to the 2nd page. This code doesn't, can you tweak it so it can? Thanks.

Comment: Add this add the end of the code `wsInt.Rows("54").ClearContents` :)

Comment: Ok, I've been working on the script some, it seems that the code is only allowing one line to be imputed, then the script stops working... 

Here is the new sheet. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Move.xlsx

Comment: The code is basically only posting 01 and said row, and won't go down to 02, etc... I don't know why either. It was working before now it seems not to want to.

Comment: Like? I only have to ask, because I thought it was line by line the same except for the sheets.

Comment: can you upload your file which has the above code embedded in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10561/discussion-between-matt-ridge-and-siddharth-rout)